# AngularJS - Refresh ngRepeat Array Data at Event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm migrating my jQuery app to AngularJS.

What I need to do, is change the Data Array when a scroll occurred, how can i do this?

I have this code with jQuery at plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/jdwxH5pmyecuWTsrutrO?p=preview

When you scroll the div, a list with the visible elements index is show.

What I want to do, is to set a directive or a filter (`ng-check-visibility`) at the ng-repeat element, like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-check-visibility>
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

And this directive change the `item` setting the value `item.visible=true` when the element is visible, otherwise, set it to false.

Can I do this with Angular? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it as a directive:

```
  var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<500; i++){
      arr.push({id: i, name: 'name'+i});          
    }
    $scope.data = {
      items: arr,
      visible: []
    };
  });

  app.directive('checkVisibility', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        data: '=checkVisibility'
      },
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        el.scroll( function() {
          var reference_top = el.offset().top;
          var reference_height = el.height();

          var $elements = el.find('.check');

          scope.data.visible = [];
          for(var i=0; i<$elements.length; i++){
            var $element = $($elements[i]);
            var element_top = $element.offset().top;
            var element_height = $element.height();

            if (reference_top < element_top + element_height &&
                reference_top + reference_height > element_top) {
                scope.data.visible.push( i );
            }
          }
          scope.$apply();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

--

```
<body  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="outer-panel" check-visibility="data">
    <div class="inner-panel">
      <div ng-repeat="item in data.items" class="check">
        {{item.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="visibles">
    {{data.visible}}
  </div>
</body>
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QN52VbsvULOf96nA4zEX?p=preview)